# When a Timer is running for each UITableViewCell, they are not being recycled properly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uikit

I have a UITableView where each cell has a label. When a button is pressed on the cell, I need to update the label for each cell every 0.01 milliseconds.

```
func tick(label: UILabel) {
    let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.01, repeats: true) { (timer) in
        // functionality to decide what to put in the label goes here
        label.text = "some string"
    }
}


// button action
@IBAction func startButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let buttonPostion = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: tableView)

    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPostion), let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? CustomCell {
        tick(label: cell.label)
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that when I scroll the UITableView the cells don't get recycled properly. For example, if I click the start button on a cell at the top, the timer begins running and its label will begin changing, then if I scroll down a label for another cell will also be changing identical to the cell at the top, without its timer being started.

What is the best way to resolve this issue?

Comment: As an alternative to @Tom Harrington's answer, I suggest coupling your timers with your data source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the cells are being reused correctly. The idea of cell reuse is that when an instance of `UITableViewCell` scrolls off the screen, that exact instance is used again when a new cell is needed at the other end. You're starting a timer in a cell, that cell gets reused, and because it's the same object it has the same timer, which is already running. If you design a cell with some state (for example, a running timer), you need to reset that state when the cell gets reused, or it will remain, unchanged.

If you're going to keep a timer in the cell, you need to arrange to stop and restart the timers when cells are reused. You could stop the timer by overriding `prepareForReuse` in your table cell class-- so that there will never be a running timer when a cell is reused. To restart them, you'd have to have your table view data source keep track of which cells have running timers, so that you can start the timer when dequeueing the cell.